# Android Layout conflict between scaleType="matrix" and adjustViewBounds="true"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am trying to make an Android `Layout` with two `ImageViews`. Images need `scaleType="matrix"` setting to move them around in code. There's paddign around them `padding="50dp"` making room for movement. I also need images to scale if they don't have enough room `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, but these two settings seem to exclude each other. How can I use both `scaleType="matrix"` and `adjustViewBounds="true"`? Is there another way to do this?

Here is my code. First Image scales (no matrix), the 2nd one doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sort_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_sort_country"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sort_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_sort_city"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />
</LinearLayout>
```